# Real-time Communication Between Client and Server using WebRTC

Tags: javascript, video, browser, webrtc, fastapi

I have a server that generates images for an application in real-time, then sends them to a browser client using WebSockets right now. This solution works fine, but ws orders and verifies transmission and even does retransmission of packets, which I don't need. I need it to be as fast as possible.

For this reason, I was thinking about switching to WebRTC for the video transmission, so a WebRTC connection between a browser (javascript) client and for example a python FastAPI or NodeJS server, where the server does the streaming.

Now, I couldn't find any working examples of this. Most of them made a connection between two browser clients. Do you know any example projects that implemented something like this in some way? It does not even have to be video, a DataChannel with some objects streamed is completely fine as well.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You should consider the `aiortc`. It is a well-known WebRTC library for Python.
Here is its [GitHub repository](https://github.com/aiortc/aiortc) and here is the [example](https://github.com/aiortc/aiortc/blob/main/examples/server/server.py).